# How can i parse URL in Android

Tags: android

I my application I should parse `URl` and I should get **id** number from **Id**

> `http://example.com/cat/detail/proc?id=147&_prof=W6IYDQZ2F2YOVBC78RUA`

How can I parse this url and get id and prof ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use  [getQueryParameter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getQueryParameter(java.lang.String))

```
 Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://example.com/cat/detail/proc?id=147&_prof=W6IYDQZ2F2YOVBC78RUA");
String id = uri.getQueryParameter("id");
String _prof = uri.getQueryParameter("_prof");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://example.com/cat/detail/proc?id=147&_prof=W6IYDQZ2F2YOVBC78RUA");
String id = uri.getQueryParameter("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<NameValuePair> parse = URLEncodedUtils.parse(URI.create("http://example.com/cat/detail/proc?id=147&_prof=W6IYDQZ2F2YOVBC78RUA"), "UTF-8");
        for (NameValuePair pair : parse) {
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!! " + pair.getName() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    }
```